# AES 256 program not working

Tags: c, encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric

So I have been attempting to implement AES-256 in C. After lots of reading around and following the wikipedia page to implement it, I managed to code it. Only when I tested it, it seemed to give the wrong output.

Code:

```
/*
AES-256
(c) 2017 Daniel Gee
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned char rcon[256] = {
    0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x4d, 0x9a, 
    0x2f, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0x63, 0xc6, 0x97, 0x35, 0x6a, 0xd4, 0xb3, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0xef, 0xc5, 0x91, 0x39, 
    0x72, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0xbd, 0x61, 0xc2, 0x9f, 0x25, 0x4a, 0x94, 0x33, 0x66, 0xcc, 0x83, 0x1d, 0x3a, 
    0x74, 0xe8, 0xcb, 0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8, 
    0xab, 0x4d, 0x9a, 0x2f, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0x63, 0xc6, 0x97, 0x35, 0x6a, 0xd4, 0xb3, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0xef, 
    0xc5, 0x91, 0x39, 0x72, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0xbd, 0x61, 0xc2, 0x9f, 0x25, 0x4a, 0x94, 0x33, 0x66, 0xcc, 
    0x83, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0x74, 0xe8, 0xcb, 0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 
    0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x4d, 0x9a, 0x2f, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0x63, 0xc6, 0x97, 0x35, 0x6a, 0xd4, 0xb3, 
    0x7d, 0xfa, 0xef, 0xc5, 0x91, 0x39, 0x72, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0xbd, 0x61, 0xc2, 0x9f, 0x25, 0x4a, 0x94, 
    0x33, 0x66, 0xcc, 0x83, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0x74, 0xe8, 0xcb, 0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 
    0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x4d, 0x9a, 0x2f, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0x63, 0xc6, 0x97, 0x35, 
    0x6a, 0xd4, 0xb3, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0xef, 0xc5, 0x91, 0x39, 0x72, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0xbd, 0x61, 0xc2, 0x9f, 
    0x25, 0x4a, 0x94, 0x33, 0x66, 0xcc, 0x83, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0x74, 0xe8, 0xcb, 0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 
    0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x4d, 0x9a, 0x2f, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0x63, 
    0xc6, 0x97, 0x35, 0x6a, 0xd4, 0xb3, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0xef, 0xc5, 0x91, 0x39, 0x72, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0xbd, 
    0x61, 0xc2, 0x9f, 0x25, 0x4a, 0x94, 0x33, 0x66, 0xcc, 0x83, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0x74, 0xe8, 0xcb, 0x8d
};

unsigned char sbox[256] = {
    0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, 0x7b, 0xf2, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0xc5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2b, 0xfe, 0xd7, 0xab, 0x76,
    0xca, 0x82, 0xc9, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0x59, 0x47, 0xf0, 0xad, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0xaf, 0x9c, 0xa4, 0x72, 0xc0,
    0xb7, 0xfd, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0xcc, 0x34, 0xa5, 0xe5, 0xf1, 0x71, 0xd8, 0x31, 0x15,
    0x04, 0xc7, 0x23, 0xc3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9a, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xe2, 0xeb, 0x27, 0xb2, 0x75,
    0x09, 0x83, 0x2c, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0xa0, 0x52, 0x3b, 0xd6, 0xb3, 0x29, 0xe3, 0x2f, 0x84,
    0x53, 0xd1, 0x00, 0xed, 0x20, 0xfc, 0xb1, 0x5b, 0x6a, 0xcb, 0xbe, 0x39, 0x4a, 0x4c, 0x58, 0xcf,
    0xd0, 0xef, 0xaa, 0xfb, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xf9, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x50, 0x3c, 0x9f, 0xa8,
    0x51, 0xa3, 0x40, 0x8f, 0x92, 0x9d, 0x38, 0xf5, 0xbc, 0xb6, 0xda, 0x21, 0x10, 0xff, 0xf3, 0xd2,
    0xcd, 0x0c, 0x13, 0xec, 0x5f, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xc4, 0xa7, 0x7e, 0x3d, 0x64, 0x5d, 0x19, 0x73,
    0x60, 0x81, 0x4f, 0xdc, 0x22, 0x2a, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xee, 0xb8, 0x14, 0xde, 0x5e, 0x0b, 0xdb,
    0xe0, 0x32, 0x3a, 0x0a, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5c, 0xc2, 0xd3, 0xac, 0x62, 0x91, 0x95, 0xe4, 0x79,
    0xe7, 0xc8, 0x37, 0x6d, 0x8d, 0xd5, 0x4e, 0xa9, 0x6c, 0x56, 0xf4, 0xea, 0x65, 0x7a, 0xae, 0x08,
    0xba, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2e, 0x1c, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0xc6, 0xe8, 0xdd, 0x74, 0x1f, 0x4b, 0xbd, 0x8b, 0x8a,
    0x70, 0x3e, 0xb5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xf6, 0x0e, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xb9, 0x86, 0xc1, 0x1d, 0x9e,
    0xe1, 0xf8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xd9, 0x8e, 0x94, 0x9b, 0x1e, 0x87, 0xe9, 0xce, 0x55, 0x28, 0xdf,
    0x8c, 0xa1, 0x89, 0x0d, 0xbf, 0xe6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2d, 0x0f, 0xb0, 0x54, 0xbb, 0x16
};

void rotate(unsigned char *w){
    unsigned char t;
    t = w[0];
    w[0] = w[1];
    w[1] = w[2];
    w[2] = w[3];
    w[3] = t;
}

void key_schedule_core(unsigned char *w, unsigned char i){
    unsigned char j;
    rotate(w);
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        w[j] = sbox[w[j]];
    }
    w[0] ^= rcon[i];
}

unsigned char *key_schedule(unsigned char *key){
    unsigned char n = 32, b = 240, *e = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * b), i = 1, j, k, t[4];
    for(k = 0; k < n; k++){
        e[k] = key[k];
    }
    j = 32;

    while(j < b){
        t[0] = e[j - 4];
        t[1] = e[j - 3];
        t[2] = e[j - 2];
        t[3] = e[j - 1];

        key_schedule_core(t, i);

        i++;

        t[0] ^= e[j - n];
        t[1] ^= e[j - n + 1];
        t[2] ^= e[j - n + 2];
        t[3] ^= e[j - n + 3];

        e[j] = t[0];
        e[j + 1] = t[1];
        e[j + 2] = t[2];
        e[j + 3] = t[3];
        j += 4;

        for(k = 0; k < 3; k++){
            t[0] = e[j - 4];
            t[1] = e[j - 3];
            t[2] = e[j - 2];
            t[3] = e[j - 1];

            t[0] ^= e[j - n];
            t[1] ^= e[j - n + 1];
            t[2] ^= e[j - n + 2];
            t[3] ^= e[j - n + 3];

            e[j] = t[0];
            e[j + 1] = t[1];
            e[j + 2] = t[2];
            e[j + 3] = t[3];

            j += 4;
        }

        t[0] = e[j - 4];
        t[1] = e[j - 3];
        t[2] = e[j - 2];
        t[3] = e[j - 1];

        t[0] = sbox[t[0]];
        t[1] = sbox[t[1]];
        t[2] = sbox[t[2]];
        t[3] = sbox[t[3]];

        t[0] ^= e[j - n];
        t[1] ^= e[j - n + 1];
        t[2] ^= e[j - n + 2];
        t[3] ^= e[j - n + 3];

        e[j] = t[0];
        e[j + 1] = t[1];
        e[j + 2] = t[2];
        e[j + 3] = t[3];

        j += 4;

        if(j > b){
            break;
        }

        for(k = 0; k < 3; k++){
            t[0] = e[j - 4];
            t[1] = e[j - 3];
            t[2] = e[j - 2];
            t[3] = e[j - 1];

            t[0] ^= e[j - n];
            t[1] ^= e[j - n + 1];
            t[2] ^= e[j - n + 2];
            t[3] ^= e[j - n + 3];

            e[j] = t[0];
            e[j + 1] = t[1];
            e[j + 2] = t[2];
            e[j + 3] = t[3];

            j += 4;
        }
    }

    return e;
}

void shift_rows(unsigned char *state){
    unsigned char t;
    t = state[4];
    state[4] = state[5];
    state[5] = state[6];
    state[6] = state[7];
    state[7] = t;

    t = state[8];
    state[10] = t;
    t = state[9];
    state[11] = t;

    t = state[12];
    state[12] = state[15];
    state[15] = state[14];
    state[14] = state[13];
    state[13] = t;
}

void mix_columns(unsigned char *state){
    unsigned char a[4], b[4], c, j;
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        for(c = 0; c < 4; c++){
            a[c] = state[(j * 4) + c];
            b[c] = state[(j * 4) + c] << 1;
            if(state[(j * 4) + c] & 0x80){
                b[c] ^= 0x1b;
            }
        }
        state[(j * 4) + 0] = b[0] ^ a[3] ^ a[2] ^ b[1] ^ a[1];
        state[(j * 4) + 1] = b[1] ^ a[0] ^ a[3] ^ b[2] ^ a[2];
        state[(j * 4) + 2] = b[2] ^ a[1] ^ a[0] ^ b[3] ^ a[3];
        state[(j * 4) + 3] = b[3] ^ a[2] ^ a[1] ^ b[0] ^ a[0];
    }
}

void encrypt(unsigned char *key, unsigned char *state){
    unsigned char *e = key_schedule(key), i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < 14; i++){
        if(i == 0){
            for(j = 0; j < 16; j++){
                state[j] ^= e[(i * 16) + j];
            }
        }else if(i == 13){
            for(j = 0; j < 16; j++){
                state[j] ^= sbox[state[j]];
            }
            shift_rows(state);
            for(j = 0; j < 16; j++){
                state[j] ^= e[(i * 16) + j];
            }
        }else{
            for(j = 0; j < 16; j++){
                state[j] ^= sbox[state[j]];
            }
            shift_rows(state);
            mix_columns(state);
            for(j = 0; j < 16; j++){
                state[j] ^= e[(i * 16) + j];
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    unsigned char key[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        message[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    encrypt(key, message);

    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        printf("%02x ", message[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Example:

```
key = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
message = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
output = c2 2a 26 68 a8 4a 1e f3 ac 40 23 05 25 50 00 02
```

Comment: Please quote the wikipedia link, just to be sure we are talking about the same link.

Comment: @MichaelWalz https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard

Comment: Put that into the question

Comment: Apparently you will have to debug it. AES is composed of different stages/steps. Unit-test each one and debug the non-correct ones.

Comment: How do you know it's wrong? Anyway, cryptography is hard. Any "my AES implementation is no workey take a look" question needs to be hit with a $400/hour bill. Everyone is using one of the top tier libraries for a reason.

Comment: Moreover, once it *does* seem to work, please do not use it in any production/security sensitive application.

Comment: why should I not use it?

Comment: The very basic principle of cryptography/information security. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own . Here they call it "the golden rule": https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/why-you-dont-roll-your-own-crypto or

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It falls under the "why isn't this code working?" category without providing a MCVE. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. There are many well-established implementations of AES. Compare your output at each stage to the output of a known-good implementation. I will assume this is for entertainment and educational purposes only. You should never implement crypto primitives on your own for production use unless you are experienced in crypto programming. It is difficult and subtle to do correctly. Things as simple as `==` are not simple in crypto.

Comment: You should not use your implementation because it may have un-noticed flaws, the major library versions have been well vetted, in many instances FIPS 140-2 certified as valid and secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book "The Design of Rijndael" (ISBN 3-540-42580-2) has a great list of test vectors in appendix D for all the intermediate steps of an AES 128 encryption. Step through your code and compare your results with those from the book. It should be easy to change your code temporarily to AES-128 to find the bugs and then switch it back to AES-256 afterwards.

After that, throw away your implementation and use an established implementation that has been thoroughly tested, since yours is vulnerable to timing attacks (because of the `if(state[(j * 4) + c] & 0x80)`), which allows an attacker to find out the secret key. To avoid this and other implementation bugs, consult a book about implementing cryptography and try to use as much preexisting code as possible instead of writing your own.